Link service does not update with Prod connection remain dev connection on CI/CD deployment
as appeared in the screenshot, when we deploy the sypapse pipelines dev to prod using CICD, the connection string does not change eventhough it is parameterished with production connection string.
Our enviroment
Dev Synapse workspace for development
Staging CICID process to validate the pipelines
Production Synapse workspace for deployment production
enter image description here
The Synpase Deployment YAML
[enter image description here][2]
enter image description here

did you parametrize these value to be updated during your deployment?

yes, I did. but it is not updating and manually need to select for each pipeline. is there any command refresh the connection whilst it is deploy into prod

could you share your template / deployment process please

@Thomas-please check the code snippet on the question body

The images are not really helpful to understand the underlying issue tbh.

if the values are not overriden it could be cause your prod synapse has source control enable ?

kindly help me exact setting on production Synapse source control or guide me on this, thanks heaps

Is it connected to a git repo ? Like you dev data factory is probably connected to git/azure devops repo. is it the same for your production instance?

sorry i mean synapse rather than data factory

no it hasn't configured to GITHUB

can you add your yaml dpeloyment please, it does not show up for the moment

sure, I have removed it due to exposed some actual connection details, I will upload it again. thank

@Thomas - can you see it clearly?

@Thomas, any update please?

Yeah i can see the image now. is it working in the staging env ?
